# Postgresql & pgAdmin: Add a default column to every new table in database

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

**Postgresql & pgAdmin: How can I add a column to every table that is created in my database?**

I want to add a "GUID" and "CreateDate" column by default to every single table that will ever be created in my database.

So if I do:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    name string
)
```

Then it should create a table with 3 columns (name, GUID, CreateDate)

Comment: Look up Triggers but more specifically DDL triggers

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "template" table and then use `LIKE` when creating new table, so that the column definitions of the template are copied to the new table.

```
CREATE TABLE template
             (guid uuid,
              createdate timestamp);

CREATE TABLE my_table
             (LIKE template,
              name text);
```

`my_table` will also have the columns `guid` and `createdate`.

Comment: This almost works, the only problem is that LIKE does not copy the DEFAULT settings, how can I fix this? For example the create date column is `CreateDate timestamp DEFAULT now()`